# Prove irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Can binomial expansion of:
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2 + \cdots$$
be used to prove that numbers such as $\sqrt{2}$ are irrational.
Also, what is the easiest way to write this expansion using sigma notation?

I had previously written it as:
$$1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\prod_{m=0}^{n-1}(p-m)}{n!}x^n$$
where p is the power

Comment: yeah I think it is wrong somewhere but not sure where

Comment: See [the binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement).

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: It is one question but has multiple parts relating to how to answer it

Comment: Here you go https://tinyurl.com/n5h66rm Lmk if you want me to explain the proof in an answer

Comment: @GFauxPas I understand up until the second line of summations but don't understand how it has been split

Comment: You could use \,$\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{1-1/2}\,$ and use the binomial series with $\,x=-1/2\,$ which **does** converge.

Comment: @HenryLee I typed out an explanation but then I realized I was using the regular binomial theorem, while the question was asking for the power series version, oops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  binomial expansion formula is  $$ (1+x)^n = \sum _0^{\infty} \binom {n}{k} x^k $$

$$(1+x)^{1/2} = \sum _0^{\infty} \binom {1/2}{k} x^k $$

The series converges for $|x|<1$ but for $x=1$ the series does not converge to $\sqrt 2$

Comment: It converges for $|x|<1$ I believe. The generalized binomial theorem is essentially a taylor series.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew it was valid only for this range but wasn't sure if this was because of an issue of convergence or just due to the accuracy of it

Comment: Yes, but to get $\sqrt 2$ we need $x=1$

Comment: yep I see that thanks

Comment: However, you could set $x = -1/2$, so $(1-1/2)^{1/2} = 1 / \sqrt{2}$ and the series converges at $x$. If you can somehow show that $1 / \sqrt{2}$ is irrational (don't ask me how), then it is an easy step to conclude $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: All this shows is that you can't use the binomial series expansion for $(1+1)^{1/2}$.